# Changing locale dynamically in Vue app doesn't update translated values on pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, localization, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I have a large-ish Vue app (using Vuetify), and I recently incorporated `vue-i18n` into it. I have my json translation files set up and working, and my calls to `$t()` working fine in my components and other `.js` files. However, what I have been unable to do is change the locale on the fly so that the text in all of my translated fields shows the appropriate language. If I change in my `new Vue18n({})` definition and save the file, it works fine, and all my translated values show up fine.

In my case, I have the choices as items on a menu,

```
    <v-icon color="primary" dark slot="activator">
        person
    </v-icon>
    <v-list dark class="primary">
      <v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile-title>{{ getUser.userId }}</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>

      <v-divider />

      <v-list-tile @click="passDialog = !passDialog">
        <v-list-tile-title>Password</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile @click="logoutClick">
        <v-list-tile-title>Logout</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile-title @click="setLocale('en')">English</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile-title @click="setLocale('es')">Spanish</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
```

and a click handler that passes the appropriate locale to a method:

```
setLocale(locale) {
  this.$root.$i18n.locale = locale;
},
```

where `VueI18n` is defined here:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

function loadLocaleMessages() {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i);
  const messages = {};
  locales.keys().forEach((key) => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i);
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1];
      messages[locale] = locales(key);
    }
  });
  return messages;
}

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  localeDir: 'locales',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
});
```

I've also tried variations, such as

```
this.$i18n.locale = locale;
```

and

```
i18n.locale = locale;
```

after also doing

```
import i18n from `@/i18n';
```

in the component. However, almost none of them change all of my field name values that have translations. It's almost as if I have to force a re-render of my translated values once the language has been changed.

Is there something different I need to do in order to get all of my translated values to update once I have selected a different language?

**UPDATE:** Based on Romain Vincent's comment below, I realized that I missed an important part of my setup. There are multiple Vuetify attributes for each field, and they are extracted to a separate `fields.js` file. For example, here are a couple field definitions from a template:

```
<v-layout row>
  <v-flex xs6>
    <v-text-field 
      v-bind="fields.userId" 
      v-model="userModel.userId"
      :disabled="!canSave"
    />
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex xs6>
    <v-text-field v-bind="fields.id" v-model="userModel.id" disabled />
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>

...

import { fields, buttons, csvFields } from '@/components/config/users';

...

data: () => ({
    fields,
...
})
```

and then here is `fields.js`:

```
import RuleGenerator from '@/utils/RuleGenerator';
import i18n from '@/i18n';

const fields = {
  userId: {
    label: i18n.t('users.generalInfo.userId'),
    // Set label to 'Email' because the username is required to be an email address.
    rules: new RuleGenerator('Email')
      .setRequired()
      .setMin(1)
      .setMax(255)
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
      .setRegEx(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
      .getRules(),
    hint: 'Must be a valid email address',
    counter: '255',
  },
  id: {
    label: i18n.t('users.generalInfo.id'),
  },
};

export default fields;
```

It's these fields that don't change locales. However, if I bind the `label` directly in the component:

```
<v-text-field 
  v-bind="fields.userId" 
  v-model="userModel.userId"
  :disabled="!canSave"
  :label="$t('users.generalInfo.userId')"
/>
```

changing the locale updates the label value just fine. So having that bound file seems to be the problem, even though it's including `i18n.js`, which is where `locale` is set.

**UPDATE 2:** It seems other people have run into this issue, too ([see this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8571)).

Comment: I think you have another problem that is preventing reactivity to occur because as far as I know, your code for chaning locales is correct. I've tried just now in the console with $vm.$i18n.locale = 'en'/'xxx' and it works immediately

Comment: @RomainVincent I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `label: i18n.t(...)`, it will only run once. Any changes in language will not change the label. One solution is to put the text keys in your fields and use $t in your component on the variable containing the text key:

`field.js`

```
...
const fields = {
  userId: {
    label: 'users.generalInfo.userId',
...
```

`component`

```
<v-text-field 
  :label="$t(fields.userId.label)"
/>
```